# What does this exception in Android Studio core mean?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What does this exception in Android Studio core mean?

`Assertion` failed:

> dataContext has no component for new ListPopupStep java.lang.Throwable

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the [code-history-mining plugin](https://github.com/dkandalov/code-history-mining). There is a related issue [here](https://github.com/dkandalov/code-history-mining/issues/14).

According comments :

> The actual problem might be that liveplugin.PluginUtil#showPopupMenu(java.util.Map) needs context for some other mini-plugin which is incorrectly attributed to code history mining. I.e. need to fix showPopupMenu and make code mining plugin work correctly when live plugin is installed.